# Taking index og existing index in python

Tags: python

If I have a  list of integers like such in python

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

and I take an index like such

```
list[4] //gives 5
```

I access the index

but if I wrap that expression in another list index, I get a strange result

```
list[list[4]] //gives 8 (or 5th index)
```

why do I access another index when I put the expression inside another expression to access the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list[4] = 5` is an integer, naturally it can be used to index into another list, or itself. Also please note that `list` is reserved in python, you should avoid naming variables with the `list` name.

Comment: Okay so it returns an integer, in that I use that for indexing the next expression?

Comment: more like it evaluates to an integer but yeah that's the idea.

Comment: it seems you are experienced w/ js. it's the same in js. `a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]`, then `a[a[2]]` is 5.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `list[4]` you get the 4th element of the list, which is `5`. When you write `list[list[4]]` it's the same as you would write `list[5]` and the 5th element of the list is `8`.